# How to send whatsapp messages via twilio and manage the replies via the mobile phone?

Tags: twilio-api

I would like to send a Whatsapp message via Twilio and be able manage the response via whatsapp mobile app. So i want the same account to be accessed via the api and the mobile App. Twilio gives me the error message below :

> "This number is registered to an existing WhatsApp account. To use
> this number, disconnect it from the existing account. Then, return to
> this page and re-enter the number. Note: It may take up to 3 minutes
> for the number to become available."

How can I accomplish this?

I use this code to send whatsapp message via Twilio :

```
  TwilioClient.Init(_Configs.Twilio.SID, _Configs.Twilio.Token);

                var message = MessageResource.Create(
                    body: whatsapp.Message,
                    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + _Configs.Twilio.FromNumberWhatsapp), 
                    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+27" + whatsapp.CellNumber.Trim().Substring(1))
                );
```

Please recommend another service provider if it cant be done via Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is correct. You cannot use a WA number on a mobile phone **and** on Twilio (or any other communications platform). If you want to use a mix of human-written and automated messages, you can build an application where a user can write the message that is then sent via the API.

Comment: Hello @IObert. Not an endorsement but from your answer this would mean a product like Flex?. I am looking through the twilio documentation and this question scenario is not mentioned in docs which seems like a valid use-case for it to be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, [Flex](https://www.twilio.com/blog/integrating-whatsapp-business-flex) can do that. Or a custom app that uses Twilio [Messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp) or [Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations)

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed will send out a text message. If someone replies to that message, you'll receive a webhook request from Twilio. You'll need to set up a web application to handle that request.

Are you using .NET?
If so, you can:

1. Create an MVC project with ASP.NET
2. Install the `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` package
3. Create a controller, i.e. `SmsController.cs`
4. Paste in the following code:

```
using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers {
  public class SmsController: TwilioController {
    public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest incomingMessage) {
      var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
      messagingResponse.Message("The copy cat says: " +
        incomingMessage.Body);

      return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }

  }
}
```

5. Run the application
6. Host your app, you can use ngrok to test it out by creating a tunnel from the Internet to your localhost.
7. Copy the public URL and add it to your Twilio Console, and configure it when a Message comes in, it should hit this URL.

If you want more details, check out the documentation on [how to Receive and Reply to Inbound SMS Messages with ASP.NET MVC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-framework#receive-and-reply-to-inbound-sms-messages-with-aspnet-mvc).